Google Earth Engine - Display or export GIF with lots of frames and/or high res
I have a script to create a gif in GEE, but if it's more than about 100 frames, or fewer but I try to increase the resolution, it will not display in the console. And as I understand a gif cannot be exported to drive for some reason. Is there a good way to create gifs in GEE? So far I can make better quality ones by screenshotting the GUi, which is not ideal! (Is there a standard script out there for drawing an ROI, setting dates and getting a timelapse gif?)
// Define geometry (Polygon)

// Define your Sentinel-2 Harmonized ImageCollection
var sentinelCollection = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_HARMONIZED')
  .filterBounds(geometry)
  .filterDate('2022-11-28', '2023-02-02')
  .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 90))
  .select(['B4', 'B3', 'B2']);

// Define Landsat 8 ImageCollection
var landsat8Collection = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T2_TOA')
  .filterBounds(geometry)
  .filterDate('2022-11-28', '2023-02-02')
  .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUD_COVER', 90))
  .select(['B4', 'B3', 'B2']);

// Define Landsat 9 ImageCollection
var landsat9Collection = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC09/C02/T2_TOA')
  .filterBounds(geometry)
  .filterDate('2022-11-28', '2023-02-02')
  .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUD_COVER', 90))
  .select(['B4', 'B3', 'B2']);

// Define visualization parameters for Sentinel-2
var visParamsSentinel = {
  bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'],
  min: 0,
  max: 1000,
  gamma: 0.5
};

// Define visualization parameters for Landsat
var visParamsLandsat = {
  bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'],
  min: 0,
  max: 1,
  gamma: 0.5
};

// Visualize Sentinel-2 images
var visualizedSentinel = sentinelCollection.map(function(image) {
  return image.visualize(visParamsSentinel).clip(geometry)
    .set('system:time_start', image.get('system:time_start'));
});

// Visualize Landsat 8 images
var visualizedLandsat8 = landsat8Collection.map(function(image) {
  return image.visualize(visParamsLandsat).clip(geometry)
    .set('system:time_start', image.get('system:time_start'));
});

// Visualize Landsat 9 images
var visualizedLandsat9 = landsat9Collection.map(function(image) {
  return image.visualize(visParamsLandsat).clip(geometry)
    .set('system:time_start', image.get('system:time_start'));
});

// Merge the visualized collections
var visualizedCollection = visualizedSentinel
  .merge(visualizedLandsat8)
  .merge(visualizedLandsat9)
  .sort('system:time_start');

// Create a FeatureCollection of the dates
var datesCollection = visualizedCollection.map(function(image) {
  return ee.Feature(null, {
    'date': ee.Date(image.get('system:time_start')).format('YYYY-MM-dd')
  });
});

// Print the dates to the console (for verification)
print('Dates in order:', datesCollection.aggregate_array('date'));

// Define the export parameters for GIF
var gifParams = {
  dimensions: 720,
  region: geometry,
  framesPerSecond: 3,
  crs: 'EPSG:3857', // You can specify the coordinate reference system if needed
  maxFrames: 10000
};

// Display the GIF in the console
print(ui.Thumbnail({
  image: visualizedCollection,
  params: gifParams,
  style: {height: '400px'}
}));

// Export the dates to a CSV file
Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: datesCollection,
  description: 'Timelapse_Dates',
  fileFormat: 'CSV',
  folder: 'outputGIF',
  fileNamePrefix: 'timelapse_dates'
});

